# Loading multiple images into a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have 42 images in a folder `'images/'` each in size `200 x 200 px` and `3` channels (RGB).

I want to get a numpy array of shape: `[42, 200, 200, 3]` to later use for training.

How do I achieve this?

I tried this code, from another post:

```
X_data = []
files = glob.glob ("images/*.jpg")
for myFile in files:
    print(myFile)
    image = cv2.imread (myFile)
    X_data.append (image)

print('X_data shape:', np.array(X_data).shape)
```

But the result is `X_data shape: (0,)` which I think is not what I what to achieve.

Comment: the glob returns an empty list. please learn to debug your code. use python's debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code out and it should work (although remove those weird spaces in the function calls). I think you just need to change the file path in `glob.glob("images/*.jpg")`. The images need to be in a folder called `images` that is in the same directory as the python file and all be of type .jpg. If they're pngs or bmp you'll need to change the glob search path